# Keyboard navigation (accessibility) with ant design- SubMenu

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, antd

I need to make my site accessible. I'm using ant-design Menu, and the Menu.Submenu is not keyboard accessible, i believe. By adding tabindex i can tab to the submenu, but clicking ENTER nothing happens- the submenu doesn't open, i have no way of programatically openning it.

Under handleKeyPress i'm able to register the ENTER click event on the submenu title but i cant get the submenu to open and show the items. Is there functionality for that?

Perhaps there's a way and i'm missing something?

```
<Menu.SubMenu onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress(event, 
"EditYourProfileSubMenu")} onTitleClick={()=>{alert('title clicked')}} 
tabIndex={0} title="Edit Your Profile" style={{ color: 'white' }}>
```

It would be very nice to have an entire Menu which is keyboard accessible, including navigation with arrows and automatic enter click triggers click events. 
But i'll also be happy with a way to programatically open ant design SubMenu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still waiting for a better solution, maybe someone will reply to
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14356

I found a meantime hacky solution for this- using Menu's openKeys prop(see https://ant.design/components/menu/). It gets an array of submenu keys to determine which are open. So using onKeyDown i listened to these events and added/removed the right submenu key from the array (using State, of course).

```
<Menu
   openKeys={this.controller.getMainMenuOpenKeys()}
   ...> 
...
    <Menu.SubMenu key={"EditYourProfileSubMenu"} 
        onKeyDown={(event) => this.handleKeyPress(event, "EditYourProfileSubMenu", true)} 
        onTitleClick={() => { 
        this.controller.setMainMenuOpenKeys(["EditYourProfileSubMenu"]) }} //sets the state which openKeys listens to
        tabIndex={0} 
        title="Edit Your Profile" style={{ color: 'white' }}>
       ...
   </Menu.SubMenu>
</Menu>
```

Adding openKeys field to menu messes with the mouse click flow, so i had to add onTitleClick and add the key to openKeys there also.

Comment: Instead of using click events, you could use onFocus and onBlur to toggle the submenu's key to the state, but then again you won't be able to navigate items with arrows keys. Your solution is mighty helpful to lessen the problem, but it is still too big of a problem. AntD's concern with accessibility just seems a bit too sketchy.